# Rotary encoder value looking sticky after using tkinter function " root.after"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, interrupt-handling, pi

I am quite new to python and tkinter ,I am working on a project where i give demand to slave device through rotary encoder value and reading feedback value from slave devices through communication.
I face issue when i use root.after () function .
Any suggestion regarding proper use of root.after () function so that my interrupt routine not affected welcome heartly.
Thank you.
Here is my code.

```
import pigpio
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
from RPi import GPIO
import serial

i="*00T%"
j="*01T%"
s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',
                baudrate=9600,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=1)

class decoder:           # class for decoding rotary encoder 
  def __init__(self, pi, gpioA, gpioB, callback):
      ----------
     ---------------
        ----------------

if __name__ == "__main__":

   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   import time
   import pigpio
   import tkinter as tk
   import board
   import busio
   rpm=0
   tor=0
   pow=0
   
   pi = pigpio.pi()
   st=1
   pos=0
   def callback(way):  # interrupt event sense on pin no 17,18

      global pos
      global st

      if st ==1:
        pos += way
      if pos >= 9999:
          pos=9999
        if pos <= 0:
          pos=0

        var.set(pos)
       
        print("pos={}".format(pos))
   def rpm_update():
     global rpm
     s.write(str.encode(i))
     print(i)
     time.sleep(0.2)
     if s.inWaiting():
      rpm=s.readline(s.inWaiting())
      rpm=rpm.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
      rpm=rpm[5:-1]
      print(rpm)

      var2.set(rpm)

   def tor_update():
     global tor
     s.write(str.encode(j))
     print(j)
     time.sleep(0.2)
     if s.inWaiting():
      tor=s.readline(s.inWaiting())
      tor=tor.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
      tor=tor[4:-1]
      print(tor)

     var3.set(tor)

   def pow_update():
    global rpm,tor,pow
    try:
     rpm=float(rpm)
     tor=float(tor)
    except ValueError:
     pass
    pow=int(rpm*tor/5252)
    var4.set(pow)

   def update(): 
     rpm_update()
     time.sleep(0.5)
     tor_update()
     time.sleep(0.5)
     pow_update()
     root.after(1000,update)
   path="/home/pi/logo.png"
   root=tk.Tk()
   img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
   panel=tk.Label(root,image=img)
   panel.pack()
   panel.place(x=195,y=10,height=50,width=80)
   root.title("Dynalec")
   root.geometry("500x600")
 
   {
    body of tkinter screen
   }
   decoder=decoder(pi, 17, 18, callback)
   root.after(1000,update)
   root.mainloop()
```

everything is working fine before root.after() function " root.after(1000,update)
but i need it because i have to read slave values in every sec and update in gui screen.

Comment: Instead of posting the whole code, please post the area where the behavior is found or reproducable

Comment: okay . i am reposting it

Comment: @CoolCloud, i reposted it

Comment: `time.sleep()` will freeze your gui for 0.5 seconds

Comment: @CoolCloud, So i have to avoid `time.sleep()` function ??But delay require for RS-485 bus communication.

Comment: Hmmmm i understand, but every `time.sleep()` will interfere with the `mainloop()` and freeze the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as a answer because long for comments, will remove soon.

Try this out:

```
def update(): 
     root.after(500,rpm_update)
     root.after(500,tor_update)
     root.after(500,pow_update)
     root.after(1000,update)
```

Do let me know.

Comment: thanks for your valuable support. performance slightly improved with ' `root.after(200,update) for everything and `time.sleep(0.1)` in rpm_update.

Comment: Hmmm this is just the only way i could think of, maybe you could wait and see if any other answers and then accept this later on, other than this im not sure if `after()` has any other side effects to the sensors

Comment: can we call update () function from a new thread and pass the value to the tkinter GUI

Comment: @ram `update()` may work sometimes it wont, sometimes `update_idletasks()` works